# Редактирование сайта прямо с хостинга

Tags: cms, веб-программирование, хостинг

Добрый день, коллеги!

Есть вопрос, какие есть способы облегчения жизни веб разработчика в редактировании закаченного на хостинг сайта на cms. Например нужно доработать новый функционал, с изменением многих структур, и записей в базе данных?

у меня два варианта (оба отстойные)

1. Залить весь сайт и базу на комп, расшарить их на локальной машине, после изменений заливать обратно, минусы - очень гемморно, большие объемы передавать приходится, ну и пока сайт на локальной доработке, его оригинал могут пополнить материалами, которые после закачки новой версии похерятся.
2. Далее скачивать по одному файлу изменять заливать обратно, очень муторно отслеживать результат, изменил пару строк, перезаписываешь файл, и так до бесконечности, ну и плюс мега много действий для простой задачи.

В общем, матерые веб девелоперы, как осуществлять сие действие по всем правилам этикета =)

Comment: git, git, git, git, mercurial

> его оригинал могут пополнить материалами

пусть материлы хранятся в БД независимо от файлов движка

> оба отстойные

отстойна сама идея:

* Любая ошибка вызывает лютый геморрой со сливанием фалйа на компьютер и заливанием обратно, т.к. движок в этот момент бесповоротно ломается
* Финальная версия хранится на каком-то там сервере, в результате чего при падении одного сервера теряется ВСЕ и невозможно оперативно поднять следующий
* Тестирование, поддержка, поиск ошибок, индентация сливаются во все тот же лютый геморрой

Comment: а особо страшно стает, когда один файл пофиксили два разработчика, оба залили - тут появляется рулетка:). Иногда это может быть один и тот  же разработчик - пофиксил локально, пофиксил на сервере, залил на сервер...

Answer (score 2):

> какие есть способы облегчения жизни веб разработчика

1. Работать в той же среде, что и хостинг. То есть - не в Windows (если, конечно, хостинг не виндовый, но люди, сознательно идущие на это, подобных вопросов не задают).

Comment: этот ответ будет неполон без слова "виртуалка" - сейчас практически на любом компьютере можно поднять виртуальную машину с чуть ли не любой ОС. Это не эмулирует ситуацию полностью согласно всем возможным критериям, но со стороны разработки на php различий заметно не будет.

Comment: Когда-то, очень давно-давно, у меня в вмплеере было 5-6 машин. Сейчас я поумнел. И работаю в дебиане, а единственный образ Windows в виртуалке запускаю разве что из ностальгии.

Answer (score 2):

Сделать копию сайта и базы в подпапке на хостинге, и дорабатывать ее.
Когда все готово, глубокой ночью, перенести из старой базы измененный/добавленный за это время контент; проверить все еще раз, и поменять "сайты" местами. Если что-то пойдёт не так, ещё можно будет откатиться назад относительно безболезнено.

Если же совсем всё сложно, надо объявить комендантский час, и запретить на какое-то время юзерам что-то менять в базе — read only. Заранее спланировать, сколько примерно времени понадобится, удвоить его, и торжественно объявить всем: такого-то числа с 8 до 16 отключаем горячую воду!

Answer (score 0):

Код сайта можно редактировать через различные IDE (типа NetBeans или Eclipse). Создав специальный проект подключенный к вашему сайту. Любое изменение, которые вы сделаете в среде разработки будет сохранено на сайте. Среды разработки также поддерживают синхронизацию с системами контроля версий git и svn. А с базой можно работать со стандартного клиента, который идет с субд MySql или oracle, подключившись к удаленной базе.